# Class Naming Convention

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

As the size of my project becomes larger, I feel there should be a convention for class names that have similar functionality.

Let's assume that there are three data handlers having similar functionality, and the only difference is the data type they handle.

There is interface `DataHandler`.

```
interface DataHandler
```

There are three different types of data, Bitmap, Video, and Sound.

Which option is more widely-used naming convention?

### Option 1.

```
class BitmapHandler

class VideoHandler

class SoundHandler
```

### Option 2.

```
class DataHandlerBitmap

class DataHandlerVideo

class DataHandlerSound
```

I am currently using option 1 since it sounds better, but I think using option 2 also has advantages, especially the size of project is large. I can easily check how many data handlers exists by sorting class names alphabetically, and it also makes people can easily figure out and use all similar type of classes using IDE's intellisense.

**EDITED**

I removed c# tag. I couldn't think that C# and Java have different naming conventions.

Comment: This question is really not appropriate here. It's more suitable for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Voting to migrate there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred option is a combination of many of the answers here.

1) Interfaces should start with an I `IDataHandler` this is common practice.
2) Name classes after Option1. Names should not describe structure. This class could easily implement several interfaces, it would provide significant clutter to list them all, and what happens when you implement a new or remove an interface due to changing requirements / updates.
3) Use namespaces to group like items. This will make discovering / understanding of the design easier (as is you intention in Option 2).

Combining these things it is apparent with little context how things work.

```
// create a context with the namespace
namespace Media.Decoders
{
  // start interfaces with an I
  IDataHandler { ... }

  // name classes descriptively 
  class BitmapHandler : IDataHandler
  class VideoHandler : IDataHandler
  class SoundHandler : IDataHandler
}

// example if these handlers were decoding media types
// imagine navigating through the structure section by section
MyLibrary.Media.Decoders.BitmapHandler
// if everything is grouped logically if I were looking for an encoder a natural place to look would be
MyLibrary.Media.Encoders.BitmapHandler
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the naming convention for an interface would be

```
IDataHandler
```

Then, your classes should be:

```
class BitmapDataHandler
class VideoDataHandler
class SoundDataHandler
```

In any case, I believe option #2 is not so relevant; in order to discover classes in your project use the *Find all References* command (for example, if you don't use ReSharper which makes things much more easier).

Answer (score 2):

My company is a very large company (Fortune 30) and the convention is to use something along the lines of your **Option 1**.  It is sufficiently descriptive enough for even massive projects and just has a nicer ring to it. :)

Your **Option 2** only serves to obfuscate the meaning or purpose of your classes without adding any semantic value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use namespaces to do the grouping.

On top of that, if project size gets in the way of retrieving files: use ReSharper. It enables you to search on partial file or class names in a very intuïtive way. Using the right tools prevents you from adhering strange standards for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 makes the most sense to me, and seems to be the convention used throughout the built-in Java classes.  For example, in the `java.io` package,

```
BufferedReader
CharArrayReader
InputStreamReader
```

are all subclasses of `java.io.Reader`.

Option 2 seems redundant, e.g. `class DataHandlerXX implements DataHandler`, and the IDE may be able to identify all subclasses of `DataHandler`, meaning you wouldn't need to rely on sorting to determine common functionality.